# How do I make two columns--one flexible--that wrap when necessary?

Tags: css

I need two columns, basically blocks side-by-side, that wrap when necessary for a responsive design.

The issue that I'm running into is that the first column/block is statically sized, but the second column/block needs to fill the remaining width. However, they should still wrap when necessary.

Say the left-most block has a static width of 200px, while the right-most fills the remaining width, BUT with a min-width of 300px. That way it should wrap (the second block placed below the first block instead of on the right side) when necessary.

I've tried a variety of methods to no avail--floating the left block, using absolute position, etc., but I can't get the results I'm looking for.

Hopefully it's possibly using CSS alone, and not using a CSS3 media query to show/hide two different versions. Or resorting to JS... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/szmka)

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="leftBar">Test</div>
  <div class="rightCnt"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0}
.leftBar {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.rightCnt {
  margin-left: 200px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width : 500px) {
  .leftBar {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  .rightCnt {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the functionality and level of efficiency I'm looking for. Is the media query the only way with this sort of approach, though?